# .Net Core 3.1 Application throws FileNotFoundException with indirect Package reference?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have an odd behavior in one of our .Net Core 3.1 projects, namely the application throws a FileNotFoundException for one of the 3rd party NuGet packages even though the file the exception referring to be missing *is* physically in the same directory.

Basically the Asp.net Core 3.1 Web Api .exe knows nothing about concrete implementations, only interfaces. (.Net Core 3.1 Class) Libaries then implement those interfaces and some of them pull in NuGet packages. It all comes together at runtime when the libraries register themselves to the .exe's IServiceCollection on startup. There's no direct project/nuget reference between the Web Api and these libraries, rather the Web Api .exe scans on startup the assemblies and calls an (interface declared) method to allow the libraries to register themselves to the host's DI container / service collection. This all works fine. However, whenever a method is now called in one of these libraries' classes that has a using statement to one NuGet package reference, the .exe throws said FileNotFoundException stating that, i.e. "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Hangfire.Core, Version=1.7.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'". That file (and all its dependencies) are in the .exe's base directory though.

Now, comes the confusing part: when adding a project reference to that class library (that references Hangfire) and doing nothing else, it works - no FileNotFoundException anymore. The assemblies in the base directory are the same BUT the only main difference is, that the .exe.deps.json file of the Web API project is with this direct project reference vastly bigger and also lists Hangfire.Core and its sub-dependencies. I can also take the .exe.deps.json file and place it in the build output of the non-project-referenced compilation state (which throws the FileNotFoundException) and then it works.

So the only difference is the .exe.deps.json file with and without these (in)direct references and I am wondering, is there any way to get out of this mess?

I'd really like to keep things loosely coupled in our application for a good reason and I would not want to pull in package references if I didn't have to.

Problem is, I don't even know where to begin to solve / work on that deps.json generation and I don't know if I even want to go there. In the old days build output was enough to run an application, having a .json file make or break an application is somewhat.. odd to me.

Comment: You need to load the assembly somehow if there's no project reference. Even if the assembly is in the same directory, it'll use the [.deps file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing) to resolve dependencies.

Comment: @davidfowl the assemblies (and their services-to-be-added) are loaded during startup by 1.) looking for files matching our file pattern then 2.) loaded via AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath) and then scanned for classes implementing a known list of interfaces and finally 4.) those implementations added to the IServiceCollection. This works, but when later on the codepath in one of these loaded assemblies reaches code calling into one of their dependencies, the FileNotFoundException occurs.

Comment: The only difference that makes it work vs not work is to add said direct reference in the Web Api project, more precisely, the deps.json file of the Web Api contains about 13kbyte more file content after compilation vs without direct reference (and no other code change). All other deps.json files remain the same (obviously). But the .exe does not pick up the class libraries deps.json file during runtime or interprets it differently or something else is going on.

Comment: @davidfowl See https://gist.github.com/joergbattermann/4511db7e25ee6ce509b92b41c773ddc0/revisions for the Web Api .exe.deps.json -with- (Rev 1) vs -without- direct reference (Rev 2) to our "Temax.Clients.Hangfire" project (that in turn references Hangfire).